# Do I need the default windows drivers or just third party when creating WIM file on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, dism, imaging

I am helping out a colleague and we have a Hyper-v VHDX file created for a windows 10 image.

I am about to mount the image (via DISM) and then via Powershell to install the drivers. I have a list of extracted drivers from running the Export-WindowsDriver powershell command. It says the exported list are 3rd party drivers.

Now do I have to be concerned about the default microsoft drivers? Should I also try to export these and install them in the WIM? Or will these be part of the OEM job when building the hardware?

Comment: But hyperV get it's VM in .vhd or .vhdx file.

Comment: Sorry typo there..correct now.

Comment: @JD. Load the image in a test environment, if you're able, to get an idea of what to expect. `Get-Help`'s description for `Export-WindowsDriver` mentions that what is exported is, "...all third-party drivers...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All default Microsoft drivers should be part of the Windows image you were using to create the VHDX, (unless you explicitly removed them.)

So you only need to add third party drivers.